# adding elements of a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

How is it possible to add an element in a vector to the previous elements. For example:

```
data = [1,3,5,6,7,9];
newData = [1,4,9,15,22,31];
```

How would I get from data to newData? I want to keep the first element, then add this to the second, add the combination of these to the third and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [cumsum](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html) function:

```
newData = cumsum(data)
```